What are downsides to "genetic matching," particularly outside of causal inference settings?
Multivariate matching methods typically involve two steps. First the user computes $D$, a matrix of the multivariate distances between units. Second, the user applies a matching function (e.g., 1:1 nearest neighbor) to input $D$ to generate matches between units. User commonly base $D$ on Euclidian Distance or Mahalanobis Distance because the latter down-weights correlated variables, i.e. those providing redundant (Fisher) information.
One matching method that has gained traction is "Genetic Matching" (Diamond and Sekhon 2013). One of the contributions of Genetic Matching is to compute $D$ via the Generalized Mahalanobis Distance (GMD), which is distinguished by adding a matrix $W$ that weights each variable's contribution to the distance calculation. Given Genetic Matching's origins in causal inference, $W$ is computed via a "genetic algorithm" that searches for weights minimizing a summary measure of covariate imbalance (e.g., mean or sum of distances) across matches between treated and untreated units. Once the algorithm finds a $W$, the $D$ matrix is computed and units are matched using the same matching function.
Question
My understanding is that Genetic Matching is appealing because it (1) uses GMD which allows more flexible weighting of variables to find optimal matches and (2) uses a relatively fast (genetic) algorithm to final optimal $W$.

Is there any non-computational downside to using GMD? Some sort of overfitting? I could see the desire for EXACT matching on certain variables leading to favor exact matching instead, but don't see much otherwise.
How can we use genetic matching outside of causal inference? Suppose we were interested in unsupervised clustering to find similar units rather than matching to promote covariate balance in causal inference. In this case, we're interested in finding matches that minimize some summary measure of dissimilarity across matches. A reasonable example might be where we want to minimize the total distance between matched units, using GMD as our distance measure. In this case, is genetic matching still going to converge on the optimal $W$? Is there actually a unique (set) of solutions to the genetic algorithm?


I wrote a blog post about genetic matching that might be of interest.

@Noah Your post motivated this! Both it and the genmatch paper focus GMD and the genetic alg to minimize "imbalance" in (quasi)experimental settings. However, it was unclear how useful genetic matching is for other applications, when optimal W minimizes some other function. Specifically, I was thinking we might want to implicitly reduce variation in the quality of matches (i.e. distance of matches) by learning a W minimizing the variance of the distribution of distances between nearest-neighbor-matched units. Not sure this application makes sense: since I think the solution would be W = 0 = d.

It's worth remembering that genetic matching is not a matching method (despite its name); it is a method of computing the distance between units that is supplied to a matching method for use in creating groups similar on the distributions of covariates. I describe genetic matching in my blog post here, which I recommend reading to fully understand my answer.
So, genetic matching should be compared to other methods of computing the distance between units, and its role in causal effect estimation should be compared to other methods of causal effect estimation.
Genetic matching involves three components: the original distance matrix, which is adjusted using the weights; the matching method that is used to match units based on the distance matrix; and the imbalance metric that is used as the objective function for use in computing the weights. Note that the weights are applied to covariates in the distance matrix, not to individual units (I mention this because the concept of weights is used in other areas of causal effect estimation, and the imbalance metric is computed using the matching weights that result from the matching method). In principle, any distance matrix that can be adjusted using a set of weights can be used, though the literature often refers to the "generalized Mahalanobis distance" (GMD) matrix (note that the Matching package, which implements genetic matching in R, uses a scaled Euclidean distance matrix treating the off-diagonal elements as zero). Any matching method that involves pairwise distances can be used, but in practice nearest neighbor matching is used. The choice of which imbalance metric to use is a matter of debate, but theoretically depends on unseen features of the potential outcome-generating model.
Given a distance matrix and matching method, the difference between genetic matching and matching without optimizing the weights is that without genetic matching, the weights are fixed to a specific value. If you get that value "right" without optimization, then genetic matching will be worse, because it has to estimate those weights. What "right" means is ambiguous, though; it generally means you achieve balance on the right terms in the potential outcome-generating model. Genetic matching can perform worse if the imbalance metric to be optimized does not balance the right terms in the potential outcome-generating model. For example, if you request that genetic matching optimizes balance on the means but imbalance on the variance causes the most bias, genetic matching may not do better than an arbitrarily chosen set of weights. That means it is important to select a good imbalance metric. Usually, this will be one that penalizes imbalance on the whole covariate distribution, not just the means, and not just the univariate distributions. The energy distance and kernel distance are two imbalance metrics that have been studied that tend to do well in practice because they penalize imbalance on the full covariate distribution.
In practice, optimizing the weights using genetic matching will uniformly outperform treating the weights as fixed (e.g., assigning a weight of 1 to the propensity score and 0 to all other covariates, which is just propensity score matching). As long as minimizing your imbalance metric reduces bias, using it in the genetic matching algorithm will reduce bias in your estimate.
However, genetic matching is limited in that it relies on matching methods that require pairwise distance. Not all matching methods do, and sometimes easing that restriction can yield better balance in the matched sample than is possible using pairwise distance matching.
Genetic matching could definitely be used outside causal inference as long as the application is appropriate. I think your idea is fine; choose weights that yield a distance matrix that yields clusters that optimize some dissimilarity metric. The genetic algorithm and its cousins are used in many applications to optimize a non-smooth surface. However, the utility of the method depends on the appropriateness of the objective function; if optimizing a dissimilarity metric that is not known to recover true clusters, it is possible for this method to perform poorly.
